# Does AWS Aurura Postgresql do automatic query splitting

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to work out if Aurora Postgres cluster endpoint does automatic query read write splitting between the reader and writer/s? Or to I need to use something like pgpool2 for the splitting?

I have attempted pushing read/writes at it, but it looks like only the reader is being hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *but it looks like only the reader is being hit?*

Only the **writer** should be hit via the cluster endpoint.

> The cluster endpoint connects you to the primary instance for the DB cluster. You can perform both read and write operations using the cluster endpoint.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html

Aurora does not do read/write splitting.  It provides you with a cluster endpoint, which automatically points to the cluster's current writer, and a read-only endpoint, which connects you to any one of the readers.

If the cluster only has one instance (Aurora doesn't technically require you to have any readers, but recovery in the event of a failure would require much more time, since the one instance would have to be rebuilt by the system if it failed -- but no data would be lost) then both endpoints take you to the writer.